# How to group notifications from different sources into one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, models

What I have right now is a Roleplay Model, and a Message Model.

I want them to share the same notification stream: They both should create a 'Notification' row which will then be displayed to the user. 
But I want the Notification also point to their parent. I thought about creating a parent_id and parent_class column so that I could get the parent object. But is there an already built in way of doing it?

I checked out Polymorphic Models, but I don't seem to really understand how to use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is exactly polymorphic models, if you add the **parent_id** and **parent_class** fields to the **Notification** model, you can easily create a polymorphic association at your notification model to implement it, here's how it would look:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Then to use it it's quite simple:

```
message = # assign the message here
notification = Notification.create(:parent => message)
```

Then you can just query the notifications and use it to be your source of all notifications.

Comment: Alright! Now I see, I also found a better explanation here than what I had before: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations